# Can anyone give me $k$ projection maps $P_i:V \to V$ ;$i=1,...,k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k Im(P_i)$ is not a direct sum but $\sum_{i=1}^k P_i=Id$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone give me $k$ projection maps $P_i:V \to V$ ;$i=1,...,k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k Im(P_i)$ is not a direct sum but $\sum_{i=1}^k P_i=Id$.

I think in $\Bbb R^2$ I can't get but in $\Bbb R^2$ I am not getting any example right now and difficult to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Ewan gave a negative answer for the case of finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$.

I just want to mention that if you consider the case of finite fields, one example can be $id$, $id$, $id$ on any vector space over $\mathbb F_2$.

Answer (score 1):

CLARIFICATION : This answers the case of finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb R$ (or any field with zero characteristic).

Such a counterexample does not exist. Indeed, let $V_i={\textsf{Im}}(P_i)$ and $r_i={\textsf{dim}}(V_i)={\textsf{trace}}(p_i)$ since $p_i$ is a projector. Since $\sum_{i=1}^k p_k=\textsf{Id}$, we have
$x=\sum_{i=1}^k px$ for any $x\in V$, whence $V=\sum_{i=1}^k V_i$ and in particular $$\textsf{dim}(V) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \textsf{dim}(V_i)=\sum_{i=1}^k r_i\tag{1}$$.

But taking the traces in $\sum_{i=1}^k p_k=\textsf{Id}$, we see that (1) must in fact be an equality, which forces the sum to be direct.

Comment: If one assumes a finite dimensional space over a field of characteristic $0$, this is correct. But OP makes no mention of such hypotheses, nor do you (though you implicitly use them). It won't be the first time a question on MSE omits hypotheses that are nevertheless intended, but it might be better to get clarity from OP on this point first.